# angular 2 sidenav items not displaying as row

Tags: javascript, html, angular

hi there I'm trying to display a sidenav with angular 2 with links listed as rows been screatching my head for half a day trying to get it working this is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmmAR.jpg

and this is my code:

```
<md-sidenav-container class="sidenav-fab-container" fullscreen>
<md-toolbar>
  <button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
  </button>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" opened="false">
  <div>
  <md-list>
    <!--<h3>links:</h3>-->
    <md-list-item>
      <button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <md-icon>add</md-icon>
      </button>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item>
      <md-icon md-list-icon>folder</md-icon>
      <a md-line>hello World</a>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item>
      <md-icon md-list-icon>folder</md-icon>
      <a>hello World</a>
    </md-list-item >
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-list-item>
      <md-icon md-list-icon>folder</md-icon>
      <a>hello World</a>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
  </div>
</md-sidenav>

<main-view-template></main-view-template>
```

```
sidenav.ts

import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import 'hammerjs';

@Component({
  moduleId : module.id,
  selector: 'side-nav-component',
  templateUrl: 'sideNav.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class sideNavComponent{
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: try to remove div inside the md-sidenav

Comment: @brijmcq tried that and no change.

Answer (score 0):

solved it in the end. changed the item type to spans and it displays properly:

```
<md-list-item>
    <button md-button>
      <md-icon>add</md-icon>
      <span>this is text</span>
    </button>
  </md-list-item>
  <br>
  <md-list-item class="side-nav-container">
    <button md-button>
      <md-icon>add</md-icon>
      <span>this is text</span>
    </button>
  </md-list-item>
  <br>
  <md-list-item>
    <button md-button>
      <md-icon>add</md-icon>
      <span>this is text</span>
    </button>
```

which now displays like this

[http://imgur.com/a/lOxEp](https://imgur.com/a/lOxEp)

thanks for the help!